# sending sms in android ( marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, smsmanager

I tried to send sms using smsmanage. problem is application send sms only first time after user given the permission to send sms. after the first  time  application doesn't ask for permission ( because user already gave the permission first time)  and it doesn't send sms either

```
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 1;

 public void requestpermisson(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null,smsbody, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156615/not-sending-message/42156702

Answer (score 1):

Just make the following changes in your code. You have not handled the case wherein permission is already granted.

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                } else {
       // permission is already granted
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
                }
            } else {
       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null,smsbody, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: i'm getting SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE in marshmallow device. in redmi 4A. can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the case when permission is granted. Put a else block in `requestpermisson()` method. Add the code for sending sms in that else block

```
public void requestpermisson(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }else{         //already has permission granted
          SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
          smsManager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null,smsbody, null, null);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```